# Matplotlib line position moving when increasing line thickness

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot two lines showing land cover along each bank of a river. As I increase the link thickness however, the line position actually moves, such that the line is offset with it appearing to start before the start (zero distance) of the analysis. As I decrease the line width, the offset reduces but doesn't fully disappear. The lines need to be relatively thick so that patterns are interpretable in the figures produced.

[Part of the figure plot - with line thickness of 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqRkE.jpg)

[Part of the figure plot - with line thickness of 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK77G.jpg)

See sample of the code for the left bank of the river below. leftBank_filled is a Pandas Dataframe with columns used being 'rev2003_LC' (= land use) and 'ColorFormula' which is the associated color for the given land use. xDist1 has values as shown in the check of x positions further down, and yL is a constant to create a horizontal line along the top (or bottom) of the plot for each bank.

```
if len(Ldist_km) == len(leftBank_filled['rev2003_LC']):
        print('plotting left')
        for Lp in range(len(leftBank_filled['rev2003_LC'])-1):
            xDist1 = [Ldist_km[Lp],Ldist_km[Lp+1]]
            xDist1List.append(xDist1)
            plt.plot(xDist1,yL,color=leftBank_filled['ColorFormula'][Lp],linewidth=3)
```

I have modified my code to check the plotting positions for the x component, I can confirm that they are expected values (see image below).

[Check of x positions used in the plotting of the land cover lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAxNG.jpg)

I have increased and decreased the line thickness to confirm this is the variable causing the issue.

Comment: Its hard to understand what you mean - if a line is tilted, lets say at 45 degrees, and  you widen the stroke, the left side of the line will start to the left of the line with the narrower stroke.  It's not clear what you want instead?

Comment: What happens between 50 and 100-ish? Are you plotting a white line?

Comment: @fdireito - yes, there is a gap in our rivers where they get too narrow (i.e. in gorges). This data (river extents etc.) originates from remote sensing, satellite techniques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below all the white lines have an *x*-span 0—1, and also the colored ones have the same *x*-span but, due to the large line width and the different "cap styles", their length or appearance is different.

[image]

**MAYBE** you want to fiddle with Matplotlib's "cap styles"...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

capstyles = ('butt',  'round', 'projecting', None)
capnames  = ('butt',  'round', 'projecting', 'default')
ys = (0.00, 0.33, 0.67, 1.00)
text_options = dict(ha='center', va='center', weight='bold', zorder=5)

for capstyle, capname, y in zip(capstyles, capnames, ys):
    plt.plot((0,1), (y,y), lw=30, zorder=3, solid_capstyle=capstyle)
    plt.plot((0,1), (y,y), lw= 1, color='w', zorder=4)
    plt.text(.5, y, capname, **text_options)
plt.xlim((-0.1, 1.1))
plt.ylim((-0.1, 1.1))
plt.yticks([])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the problem, maybe provide a reproducible example.

But sure if you use a bigger linewidth it will expand on both sides from the value you are plotting, see:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

xmin, xmax = 0, 3
lines_position = np.arange(xmin, xmax, 0.2)
lines_ymin, lines_ymax = 0, 0.02

# Plot vertical lines
kwargs = {"x": lines_position, "ymin": 0, "ymax": 0.02, "alpha": 0.5}
# with linewidth=10
ax.vlines(**kwargs, linewidth=10, color="red", label="lw=10")
# with linewidth=1
ax.vlines(**kwargs, linewidth=1, color="black", label="lw=1")

# Better viz
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(xmin, xmax, 1))
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(xmin, xmax, 0.1), minor=True)
ax.xaxis.grid(which="major")
ax.xaxis.grid(which="minor", linestyle=":")
ax.set_ylim(None, 0.3)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: vertical lines]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @paime. In the instant you have plotted, although the y values are 0 and 0.02 respectively, I have found when I have increased the thickness/width the plot appears to start at say -0.02 in your example? Obviously my plot is horizontally aligned?

Comment: One thing I note is that in your `xDist1List` the first item for example is `[0.0, 0.1]`, so a single line segment moves along the x-axis ? i.e. you are drawing horizontal segment instead of vertical segments as I do ?

Comment: It would be useful if you provide a reproducible example, with fake data, as I did.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to comment on @paime's answer, but here is a reproducible example of the problem, basically the line end appears to get padded by the linewidth too:

```
# import modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

xmin, xmax = 0, 50
line_x = np.arange(xmin, xmax+1, 1.)
line_y1 = np.ones(len(line_x))
line_y2 = np.ones(len(line_x))*2

# Plot horizontal lines
plt.plot(line_x, line_y1, '-', linewidth=10, color="red", label="lw=10")
plt.plot(line_x, line_y2, '-', linewidth=3,  color="black", label="lw=3")

# Better viz
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(xmin, xmax+1, 10))
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(xmin, xmax, 1), minor=True)
ax.xaxis.grid(which="major")
ax.xaxis.grid(which="minor", linestyle=":")
ax.set_ylim(0, 10.)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/z31VUT0.png)
I can't post the image directly due to low rep.

I have had a poke around in linestyle properties and similar and can't find a solution to this problem. Only suggestion would be to draw white polygons over the top up to the desired edge using patches, but very unsatisfying.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).